# Patching the same module for every test

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

If I have multiple tests that patch the same module, is there a way to not have to patch it in every test (namely, factor it out)?

```
def test_1(mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(module, 'method')
    # run test

def test_2(mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(module, 'method')
    # run test

def test_3(mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(module, 'method')
    # run test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is, take a look at [autouse fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html#using-autouse-fixtures-and-accessing-other-fixtures) in the official pytest docs